# How to avoid relative imports in modules intended to be bundled?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm developing a module that doesn't have a build that the user imports. Instead, he imports individual components and then bundles them along with his code. However, those components share utilities and I want to import them without going through relative path hell.

I know that's a pretty common question and I did some research. Suppose I have `module/components/foo/bar/baz/index.js` that wants to import `module/utils/helper.js`

#### Option 1

Just use relative paths and do:

```js
import helper from '../../../../utils/helper'
```

#### Option 2

Use the [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package and have:

```js
import helper from '@utils/helper'
```

This would work in Node.js because modules are resolved at runtime. However, let's say the module user has Webpack and imports the module:

```js
import component from 'module/components/foo/bar/baz'
```

Webpack wouldn't be able to resolve `@utils` unless the user specifies that alias in **his own** Webpack configuration. That would be pretty annoying.

#### Option 3

Use Webpack aliases in *webpack.config.js*:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@utils': path.join(__dirname, 'utils')
    }
  }
}
```

This would work fine if [the module was pre-bundled](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/). But as I've previously mentioned, I want the library to be usable with ES6 imports so that users can bundle only the parts they need.

#### Option 4

I could use the module name in the module's own source code:

```js
import helper from 'module/utils/helper'
```

This appears to solve the problem, but I think it's a pretty bad solution. For development, you'd have to create a symlink `node_modules/module -> module`. I'm sure this hides many potential issues and collaborators would have to manually do it as well.

---

Is there a way to avoid relative paths while allowing the library to be used with ES6 imports?